# Remove toolbar from product list via local.xml

Tags: layout, blocks

I am used to using local.xml for my layout updates, however I cant seem to remove the toolbar from the product list block using either the remove or unsetChild methods.

Can anyone say if this is actually not possible or am i doing something wrong?

I have tried:

```
<action method="unsetChild">  
    <alias>toolbar</alias>
</action>
```

and

```
<action method="unsetChild">  
    <alias>product_list_toolbar</alias>
</action>
```

and also the `<remove name="" />` methods too but nothing works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And you won't be able to remove it without overriding something. Here is how the `getToolbarBlock()` method looks like:

```
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
        if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
    return $block;
}
```

This means that if a block with a certain name (value returned by`getToolbarBlockName`) exists in the layout then that block will be returned. otherwise a new block is created with type `catalog/product_list_toolbar` and that is returned by the method.

**[EDIT]**
I just had a crazy idea. Why not change the toolbar block type? That way it won't be rendered as a toolbar. I haven't tried it but I think it's worth it.
Something like:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <block type="core/template" name="product_list_toolbar" />
</reference>
```

I mean adding a block with the same name but a different type. If it doesn't work please don't donwvote; it is just in idea :)

Comment: Its code like this that really annoys me with Magento.  So now i need to go override classes or templates where some nice layout xml would have sufficed

Comment: I've updated the answer with an idea crazy enough to work.

Comment: @MartyWallace - at least there is layout XML in the first place. I think that layout XML falls into the "give a mouse a cookie" category once people know how to use it.

Comment: Different type can cause problems, as we need the setCollection function to set paging

Comment: @Marius I tested your "crazy idea" and it works great. No side-effects noticed so far.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly. Nice. I've been meaning to try it, but I guess I forgot. Thanks for the input.

Comment: really frustrating, an even less intrusive hack would be to hide it using jquery with jQuery( document ).ready(function(){jQuery('.limiter').hide();});

Comment: Also note that if you really need the toolbar, like for Ajax pagination, then removing the toolbar or using core/template as its class will not work. In that case, hiding the toolbar is a better option.

Answer (score 9):

In your `local.xml` file add the following:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <!-- Remove Toolbar by setting a blank template -->
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template /></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: For a custom layout update on a category page, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't remove this or unset this via XML due to some weird way the devs built the thing. However you can create a blank template and point the toolbars to this blank template instead.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>theme/package/blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>theme/package/blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>theme/package/blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

That will remove it from Normal categories, Anchored categories and the search page.