# How to remove the product_list_toolbar from a specific catalog page?

Tags: layout, catalog, category, magento-1.9

How do can you remove the product_list_toolbar from a specific category page??

I've tried adding the below to the Custom Layout Update of the the category in **Catalog -> Manage Categories**  under the **Custom Design** tab from the **Magento Admin Panel**.

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <remove name="product_list_toolbar" /> 
</reference>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, removing the toolbar with something like `<remove name="product_list_toolbar" />` does not work (see e.g. [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/remove-toolbar-from-product-list-via-local-xml)).

You can do it like that:

1. Create an empty template under `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/blank.phtml`
2. Set the empty template for the toolbar block:

In your `local.xml` for a specific category with the ID `5`:

```
<CATEGORY_5>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_5>
```

Or directly in the custom layout update text field in the admin:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>blank.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```